# Is there a way to tell programmatically which type of layout is a view's parent

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an `ImageView` that I am resizing dynamically and I need to know if the `ImageView`'s parent is a `RelativeLayout` or a `LinearLayout`.  Is there a way to tell this programmatically?

```
public class ResizeableImage extends ImageView {

View parent = null;

public ResizeableImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defaultStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defaultStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int xNew, int yNew, int xOld, int yOld)
{
    super.onSizeChanged(xNew, yNew, xOld, yOld);
    parent = (View) this.getParent();
    int parentHeight = parent.getHeight();
    int parentWidth = parent.getWidth();

    //parent.setMinimumHeight(yNew);
    //parent.setMinimumWidth(xNew);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) parent.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = yNew;
    params.width = xNew;
    parent.setLayoutParams(params);


}
```

}

In order to set the parent's new size (and for extensibility), I need to know whether it's a RelativeLayout, or any other kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `getParent()` and do an `instanceof` check to see whether it is a certain type of interest (e.g., `getParent() instanceof RelativeLayout`).

Note that in this case, `width` and `height` are defined on [`ViewGroup.LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html), the base class for all `LayoutParams` classes, so you could just cast to that and avoid tying yourself to `RelativeLayout`, etc.